# What is a hit called, that is not a home run, but still allows the batter to make it around the bases?

Tags: baseball

I know about singles, doubles and triples, depending on where the batter ends up, while the ball is in the out field, but what if the batter has enough time to make it all the way around? Is it still a home run? Or is that what a home run actually is?

Comment: A single/double/triple isn't defined solely by where the batter ends up, but also which base the batter could have reached without the benefit of an error or defensive decision. For example, runner on third, and the batter singles to right field. The outfield could throw to second, conceding the run but holding the batter-runner at 1st base. If they attempt to throw the runner out at home, the batter can advance to second. Whether the run scores or not, the batter is credited with a single, but advancing to second on the throw home.

Comment: To complicated matters further, maybe the throw home beats the runner easily, and he tries to return to 3rd. The catcher might throw to the third baseman, but throws the ball over his head. The batter *still* gets credited with a single, with any additional advancement attributed to the throw home and/or the catcher's throwing error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A home run is when a batted ball enables the batter to make it around the bases and touches home plate without the defense committing errors. Hitting the ball over the outfield fence is the easy way to get a homer. The harder way is to run around the bases while the fielders attempt to tag you out. We call this type of home run an "inside-the-park home run".

Comment: This is the answer you're looking for.  Also consider cases where the batter hits either a single, double, or triple, and together with fielding errors, the batter makes it home.  In any of these cases it would be scored a single double or triple (depending on what base he reached before the misplay(s) began), with additional fielding errors as part of the ruling.

Comment: A 4-base error is also possible, where no hit is recorded.

Comment: ...or a past ball strikeout, with errors.